# Adding roles dynamically to the asp.net role provider

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider, isinrole

I'm using the Asp.Net Role Provider that contains some roles. I would like to add some other roles that are coming from another database. Is there a way to do some kind of "union" between roles coming from the role provider and roles coming from my other database ?

To be more precise, I'm using forms authentication, I retrieve roles from my other database and store them in the FormsAuthenticationTicket. Then in AuthenticateRequest from Global.Asax, I generate the principal with the list of roles. But later when using User.IsInRole, it does not work for the list of roles I have assigned in AuthenticateRequest. What's the right direction to go ?

Christian

Comment: Either you have to a) override method GetRolesForUser (which is what IsInRole uses) in a custom role provider (IPrincipal) to use your primary roles table instead, or b) ugly: keep those two tables sync'd up, or c) use a different custom method to replace your use of IsInRole (also fairly ugly).  The answer below would be a variation of b.

Comment: What I finally did is to store roles from my external database in HttpContext.Current.Items while leaving the RoleProvider do its job from its side. It makes role checking a little bit tricky but it is just an ugly quick win for me here. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create roles at runtime:

```
Dim strNewRole as String = "NEW"

If Not Roles.RoleExists(strNewRole) Then
    Roles.CreateRole(strNewRole)
End If
```

So you can still use your code to retrieve roles from another database and then use the code above for every role.